# how to append data in python

Tags: python, append

I would like to append data in case of conditions are met but my program return an error message which is:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`

I don't see what is my problem.

I would like to get:
`[{"ID": 10,"Type": 10}]' if fonds== True...

or if fonds= True, indice=True and categorie=True, I would like to get:

```
query = [{"ID": 10,
          "Type": 10,
           },
         {"ID" : 20,
          "Type" : 20
            }, 
          {"ID" : 30,
          "Type" : 30
          }]
```

```
def data(fonds=True, indice=True, categorie=True):
    query = []
    if fonds:
        query = query.append({"ID": 10,
                              "Type": 10
                              }
                             )
    if indice:
        query = query.append({"ID" : 20,
                              "Type" : 20
                              }
                             )
    if categorie: 
        query = query.append({"ID" : 30,
                              "Type" : 30
                              }
                             )
    return query

df = data(fonds=True, indice=True, categorie=False)
df
```

Comment: When you do `query = query.append` for the first time you overwrite `query` with `None` because `.append` doesn't return anything

Comment: The `append()` function does not return anything.  Just use `query.append(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you are reassigning the query variable with the result of the append method.

You should do:

```
    query = []
    if fonds:
        query.append({"ID": 10, "Type": 10})
    if indice:
        query.append({"ID": 20, "Type": 20})
    if categorie:
        query.append({"ID": 30, "Type": 30})
    return query

df = data(fonds=True, indice=True, categorie=False)
print(df)
```